# How to reformat columns in a table from a Word template

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I am designing a resume, using the [Swiss design resume](https://create.microsoft.com/en-us/template/swiss-design-resume-cee55c90-3835-4886-a792-b504a3d54461) template. The only change I want to make is with the 4 columns at the bottom (see screenshot below). I would like to combine the two columns in the middle, to be one large columns, with a 2-column list inside. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

I am using Word for Mac, v. 16.82.

Comment: What do you mean by merging? Do you mean just combining the two black lines to one line?

Comment: That would be fine. I was just thinking it would be easier to have a 3 column table, with a wide middle column. But I suppose either would work. Drawing an extra rectangle between the 2 middle rectangles isn't optimal, because you'd have to move it every time you adjust that bottom table.

Answer (score -1):

You can't change the columns, since the entire document is one large
table, but you can do this on a new copy of the document:

- Select the two cells across the row with the black boxes.
  Select the black box, the space, and the next black box
- Merge the selected two cells and space by using
  *Layout pane > Merge group > Merge Cells*
- This will result in a single black bar across the two cells
- Select the two empty cells across the row with the black boxe
- Delete the contents of the two blocks you wish to merges.
- Select the two cells
- Merge the selected two cells by using
  *Layout pane > Merge group > Merge Cells*
- Insert a new table inside this new merged cell with one row
  and two columns
- Copy the contents of the two cells from the original document
  to the new table inside the merged cell.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't change the black bar(s) on top, though.

Comment: It does, since the black lines are just cell-borders, and the two cells were merged.

Comment: Here is what my results look like: https://imgur.com/8RnVP8Q. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I added an image of my result from the 3rd step. To select the two (now empty) cells: Click inside one cell, hold Shift and click in the second cell to select both, then click in the Layout pane, Merge group, on Merge Cells.

Comment: Ok, I figured out the step that you left out: first you need to select across the row with the black boxes. select the black box, the space, and the next black box, and merge these. then do the merging of the empt cells below.

Comment: That's certainly one method of doing that.

Comment: Please update it with the correct steps, as per my comment above

Comment: I added info for the selection step.

Comment: No, you didn't.

Comment: This is the way I did it and the result is shown in my answer. If you would rather not thank me for my help, it's your choice.

Comment: Please integrate my comment above that points out the missing step in your answer.

Comment: I don't really understand the difference between the two methods, but have it your way.

Comment: Since the answer obviously helped you and you are even editing it to be just right, please tick the answer.